# REST API for custom action other than PUT/POST/GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, sinatra

I am writing a REST API that basically gives two resources: `Users` and `Cars`. With the API, you can POST/GET each resource.

But now I have a custom action that will basically give a new car to a user. This will require a cron job in the back end and do the operation. It doesn't fit the model of POST/PUT. I am just wondering what's the best route for this?

I thought of:

```
/addNewCarToUser/:user_id
```

I know this question is too localized but I am just wondering if it's just a judgment call or if there's a convention for this type of request?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. Do cars only exist if they belong to users? Or can they exist on their own?

If they are only in the context of belonging to a User, I would just have Cars belong to Users and have a route like this to create a new one:

`POST /users/:id/cars`

Or you can specify who the owner by a car has_one owner (seems counterintuitive, but data-wise a car often has 0 or 1 owner). The route could be:

`POST /cars?user_id=######`

Another sensible relation would be to have a third resource Ownerships, and then you could create a new car and then a new ownership, because creating a car and giving it to a user would be 2 new resources.

```
POST /cars
POST /ownerships
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, "addNewCarToUser" is an action an therefore it breaches the resource principal.

I could think of

/user/:user_id/cars

This would be the resource to GET or POST.

Answer (score 0):

I would perform a `POST` since this action will result in the creation of new data.

Not sure what naming convention you're using, but I would do something like this:

```
/users/:id/new_car # via POST
```